# Magnetization ($z$-basis) of a 1D Transverse Ising Model

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, ising-model, spin-chains

I'm trying to find the magnetization $\langle\sigma_{z} \rangle$  of a 1D transverse Ising chain and plot it as a function of the transverse field $\lambda$. More specifically, I want to plot this for different values of $N$ (number of spins) for instance, $N=4,8,16,32$ etc. This is at zero temperature. The Hamiltonian of the system is this
$$
  H = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}^{x} \sigma_{i+1}^{x} + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}^{z} .
$$
Introducing periodic boundary conditions I have the Hamiltonian as
$$
   H = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}^{x} \sigma_{i+1}^{x} + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_{i}^{z} + \sigma_{1}^{y} \sigma_{2}^{z}... \sigma_{n-1}^{z} \sigma_{n}^{y} .
$$
In particular I want to express the value of the magnetization solely as a function of $\lambda$ (if possible) and see how it changes with $N$.
I'm expecting to see a kind of step function which becomes smoother as $N$ increases. Initially the spins starting in a paramagnetic phase and then moving to a ferromagnetic one.

Comment: Sorry why are there $\sigma^y$'s?

Comment: There will be no step function.  Also, what is your question?

Comment: @jacob1729 Presumably the boundary term couples to the global parity in the z basis.  However, this is what I know from mapping to free fermions - then you get this effect in the fermion model.  I would suspect that this is the kind of Ising model you get when transforming back a periodic free fermion chain.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch What is the equation that relates $\lambda$ and $\langle \sigma_{z} \rangle$?

Comment: Giving an equation would be a valid answer?  (And it is $\langle\sigma_z\rangle$, not $\langle\sigma_x\rangle$?)  In any case, this can be solved by mapping the system to free fermions via the Jordan-Wigner transformation.

Comment: Yes, and it is definitely $\langle \sigma_{z} \rangle$. I've seen examples of the magnetization calculated in papers (example Pfeuty). However, in his Hamiltonian (as a specific case) there are $\Gamma$ and $J$ terms that are not in the above Hamiltonian. I'm trying to find a function, that shows this change in magnetization (for the ground state) as the external magnetic field is increased. A function
that is expressed in variables that I know i.e. $\lambda$, $N$.

Comment: Why are you interested in that?

Comment: The aim is to explore the behavior of an chain of increasing length and see what shape that function tends to. Beyond that, the significance of $\langle \sigma_{z} \rangle$ is that it is in the computational-basis. So a comparison could be made to say a quantum simulator down the line.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Pfeuty's 1970 article, the $\Gamma$ and $J$ terms are indeed in the above Hamiltonian. You just need to identify $\lambda=\Gamma/J$. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/542757/49107) may be useful to you, as it shows what function the magnetization tends to. I don't know an analytical expression involving the number of sites $N$, but it should be fairly straight-forward to calculate the magnetization numerically.

Answer (score -2):

In the thermodynamic limit, the magnetisation of the one-dimensional transverse field Ising model is $m^2(\lambda) + c$, where $c\propto|r-r’|$. However, this is only when $N\to\infty$. For finite $N$, there is no magnetisation ever.

Comment: The question asks for the magnetization *along* the field.