# How to take into account finite temperature in transverse Ising chain?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, temperature, ising-model, spin-models, spin-chains

A similar question has  already been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169103/)

What I'm wondering is how to take into account finite temperature in the  transverse Ising chain and see how that affects the magnetization. The reason why I find it difficult to consider a finite T is that the Hamiltonian seems to be the same as in the $T=0$ case, in particular:

$H=-J\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\sigma_{i}^{x}\sigma_{i+1}^{x}+g \sigma_{i}^{z})$

and I don't know how to implement the fact that T is finite (non-zero).

So my question is: how does one take into account finite $T$ as opposed to the $T=0$ case, and how does that affect, for example, the calculation of the magnetization?

Comment: You need to compute the partition function $Z=e^{-\beta H}$, where $H$ is your hamiltonian.  Usually people only find the ground state of transverse Ising, but it *is* free Majorana fermions, so you do know all the eigenstates. What is hard is the spin correlators of course. That is hard even at $T=0$.

Comment: @mikestone Ok but after I calculate Z how do I find the Magnetization? I know that it should be the derivative of free energy (which I can calculate with Z) with respect to magnetic field, but here I don't have a B field.

Comment: @mikestone Or maybe I can I can calculate it as $\frac{Tr(e^{-\beta H}\sigma^{z})}{Z}$ ?

Comment: Calculating $\langle \sigma^z\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(\sigma^z e^{-\beta H})/Z$ is very hard, but what can be calculated is $\langle\sigma^z_{1+j} \sigma^z_{1}\rangle$ in the limit $j \rightarrow \infty$, see https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9509147 for the finite-temperature result. One should have $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\langle\sigma^z_{1+j} \sigma^z_{1}\rangle = \langle \sigma^z \rangle^2$.